# Disadvantages of maintaining a global counter in redis

Tags: redis

If I was performing millions of `hincrby` operations on a value stored at key within minutes, and simultaneously getting the value to display it, would there be any race conditions I'd need to be aware of? Moreover, would `hincrby` commands automatically queue as they scale up?

Basically I'm looking to set and get a global counter for a highly frequent event in my app (hundreds of events per second, leading to hundreds of set and get commands per second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis commands are executed atomically, and there's **NO** race condition.

Redis is very fast, and it can take thousands of fast operations (e.g. `HINCRBY`) per second. So I think in your scenario (i.e. hundreds of operations per second), you don't need worry about the performance. Also, why not do a benchmark test :)

Comment: Yep, will benchmark everything. My only gripe was that I can't use `pipeline` here, I'd be thrashing the redis server when traffic is high.

Comment: @HassanBaig If consistency doesn't matter too much, you can consider reading from Redis slaves to scale out

Answer (score 0):

To avoid thrashing the Redis server when traffic is high, one option is to get your app to limit the rate it writes to Redis. Your app servers could keep their own internal counters and only persist their totals to Redis at a known interval (e.g. every 10 seconds).

A simple code example of what I mean:

```
var mycounter = 0;

// maintain internal counter
var increment = function() {
  mycounter++;
};

// only write to Redis once every ten seconds 
setInterval(function() {
  var val = mycounter;
  if (val > 0) {
    mycounter = 0;
    redisclient.hincrby("mykey", "counter", val);
  }
}, 10000);
```

There is a risk to counts never reaching Redis, but at least Redis write-rate is a known quantity.